# BigDecimal can't be coerced into BigDecimal

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml, bigdecimal

This should be pretty simple, yet it's blowing up. Any ideas?

```
d = BigDecimal.new("2.0")
YAML::load({:a => d}.to_yaml)
TypeError: BigDecimal can't be coerced into BigDecimal
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/inspector.rb:86:in `inspect'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/inspector.rb:86:in `inspect'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/inspector.rb:86:in `block in <module:IRB>'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/inspector.rb:30:in `call'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/inspector.rb:30:in `inspect_value'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:260:in `inspect_last_value'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `output_value'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
from /Users/benjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'Maybe IRB bug!
```

Comment: Hmmm, looks like `to_yaml` is confused on BigDecimal, `BigDecimal.new("2.0").to_yaml` says `"--- !ruby/object:BigDecimal {}\n\n"`.

Comment: Yep. `ActiveSupport` seems add a core extension for this, but on my platform I get `BigDecimal.new("2.0").to_yaml` -> `"--- 2.0\n"`. So although it works better, it still doesn't convert to a full `BigDecimal`: http://apidock.com/rails/BigDecimal/to_yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that has been [reported](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/31) and [fixed](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/commit/33ce8650bac29190dde937b1b7d3e21fd06926e7).

The best solution would be upgrade to the latest Ruby (the fix is in patch level 194 onwards).

If you can’t upgrade your Ruby version, you can get the fix by installing the [Psych gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/psych). If you do this you’ll need to add `gem 'psych'` before you `require 'yaml'` (or add it to your `Gemfile` if you’re using Bundler) to load the code from the gem rather than from the standard library..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I ran into that once. Here's a version of what I did:

[YAML & BigDecimal workaround](http://blog.induktiv.at/archives/6-YAML-and-BigDecimal-a-temporary-solution.html)

Comment: Unfortunately that solution no longer works. I'm on ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Here's David's answer, updated to work in 1.9.3 thanks to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530412/cant-define-singleton-method-encode-with-for-bigdecimal):

```
require 'yaml'
require 'bigdecimal'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
class BigDecimal
  def to_yaml(opts={})
    YAML::quick_emit(object_id, opts) do |out|
      out.scalar("tag:induktiv.at,2007:BigDecimal", self.to_s)
    end
  end
end
YAML.add_domain_type("induktiv.at,2007", "BigDecimal") do |type, val|
  BigDecimal.new(val)
end
x = BigDecimal.new("2.0")
puts x.to_yaml
y = YAML.load(x.to_yaml)
puts x == y
```