# Getting big decimals back from a yaml-serialized field in the database with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, bigdecimal

Using Ruby on Rails I have a couple of fields that are serialized (arrays or hashes mostly). Some of those contain `BigDecimal`s. It is very important that those big decimals remain big decimals, but Rails is turning them into floats. How do I get `BigDecimal`s back?

Looking into this issue I found that serializing a big decimal in plain Ruby, without Rails, works as expected:

```
BigDecimal.new("42.42").to_yaml
 => "--- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.4242E2\n...\n"
```

but in a Rails console it doesn't:

```
BigDecimal.new("42.42").to_yaml
 => "--- 42.42\n"
```

That number is the string representation of the big decimal, so it's all-right. But when I read it back it is read as a float, so even if I convert it to `BigDecimal` (something I don't want to do as it's error prone), it is possible I'll lose precision, which isn't acceptable for my app.

I tracked down the culprit to `activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb` which overrides the following method in BigDecimal:

```
YAML_TAG = 'tag:yaml.org,2002:float'
YAML_MAPPING = { 'Infinity' => '.Inf', '-Infinity' => '-.Inf', 'NaN' => '.NaN' }

# This emits the number without any scientific notation.
# This is better than self.to_f.to_s since it doesn't lose precision.
#
# Note that reconstituting YAML floats to native floats may lose precision.
def to_yaml(opts = {})
  return super if defined?(YAML::ENGINE) && !YAML::ENGINE.syck?

  YAML.quick_emit(nil, opts) do |out|
    string = to_s
    out.scalar(YAML_TAG, YAML_MAPPING[string] || string, :plain)
  end
end
```

Why would they do that? And more importantly, how do I work-around it?

Answer (score 17):

The ActiveSupport core extension code you mentioned is "already" fixed in the master branch (the [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d8ed247c7f11b1ca4756134e145d2ec3bfeb8eaf) is about an year old and undoes an implementation as old as [Rails 2.1.0](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.1.0/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/BigDecimal/Conversions/to_yaml)), but since Rails 3.2 only gets security updates, your app might be stuck with the old implementation.

I think you'll have three options:

1. Port your Rails app to Rails 4.
2. Backport Psych's `BigDecimal#to_yaml` implementation (monkey patch the monkey patch).
3. Switch to Syck as YAML engine.

Each option has its own disadvantage:

**Porting to Rails 4** seems to me the best alternative, if you have the time to do so (the commit mentioned above is available in Rails since v4.0.0.beta1). Since it's not released yet, you'd have to work with the beta. I don't suspect any grand changes to come, though some GSoC [ideas](https://github.com/rails/gsoc2013/wiki/Ideas) read as if they still could make it into the 4.0 release...

**Monkey patching** the ActiveSupport monkey patch should be fairly less complex. Though I did not find *the original* implementation of `BigDecimal#to_yaml`, a somewhat [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724253/bigdecimal-cant-be-coerced-into-bigdecimal) led to [this commit](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/commit/33ce8650bac29190dde937b1b7d3e21fd06926e7). I guess I'll leave it to you (or other StackOverflow users) how to backport that particular method.

As quick'n'dirty workaround, you could simply **use Syck as YAML engine**. In the same question, user [rampion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9859/rampion) [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10728941/766783) this piece of code (which you could place in an initializer file):

```ruby
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'

class BigDecimal
  def to_yaml(opts={})
    YAML::quick_emit(object_id, opts) do |out|
      out.scalar("tag:induktiv.at,2007:BigDecimal", self.to_s)
    end
  end
end

YAML.add_domain_type("induktiv.at,2007", "BigDecimal") do |type, val|
  BigDecimal.new(val)
end
```

The main disadvantage here (besides the unavailability of Syck on Ruby 2.0.0) is, that you can't read *normal* BigDecimal dumps within your Rails context, and everybody who want's to read your YAML dumps, needs the same kind of loader:

```ruby
BigDecimal.new('43.21').to_yaml
#=> "--- !induktiv.at,2007/BigDecimal 43.21\n"
```

(Changing the tag to `"tag:ruby/object:BigDecimal"` won't help either, since it yields `!ruby/object/BigDecimal`...)

---

### Update – things I learned so far

1. The odd behaviour seems to date back to times of Rails 1.2 (you might also say Feb'2007), as per [this blog entry](http://web.archive.org/web/20090530104151/http://blog.chrispcritter.com/articles/2007/02/11/bigdecimal-and-yaml-dont-get-along).
2. Modifying the `config/application.rb` in this way did **not** help:

   ```ruby
   require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

   # (a)

   %w[yaml psych bigdecimal].each {|lib| require lib }
   class BigDecimal
     # backup old method definitions
     @@old_to_yaml = instance_method :to_yaml
     @@old_to_s    = instance_method :to_s
   end

   require 'rails/all'

   # (b)

   class BigDecimal
     # restore the old behavior
     define_method :to_yaml do |opts={}|
       @@old_to_yaml.bind(self).(opts)
     end
     define_method :to_s do |format='E'|
       @@old_to_s.bind(self).(format)
     end
   end

   # (c)
   ```

   At different points (here *a*, *b* and *c*) a `BigDecimal.new("42.21").to_yaml` has yielded some interesting output:

   ```ruby
   # (a) => "--- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.4221E2\n...\n"
   # (b) => "--- 42.21\n...\n"
   # (c) => "--- 0.4221E2\n...\n"
   ```

   where *a* is the default behaviour, *b* is caused by the ActiveSupport Core Extension and *c* should have been the same result as *a*. Maybe I'm missing something...
3. On carefully rereading you question, I had this idea: Why not serialize in another format, like, JSON? Add another column to your database and migrate over time like this:

   ```ruby
   class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
     # the old serialized field
     serialize :preferences

     # the new one. once fully migrated, drop old preferences column
     # rename this to preferences and remove the getter/setter methods below
     serialize :pref_migration, JSON

     def preferences
       if pref_migration.blank?
         pref_migration = super
         save! # maybe don't use bang here
       end
       pref_migration
     end

     def preferences=(*data)
       pref_migration = *data
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: That is such a good answer. I can't comment on it's correctness, but its really readable and clear. You quickly give a clear answer to thee question, then go on to deal with the ramifications. You are discussed the benefits and possible risks of each suggestion. A nice piece of work. Well done.

Comment: Thanks. I just try to be helpful (although, sometimes the english language is in my way ;-))

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am running the latests stable version of Rails, so I wouldn't call this being stuck in an old version. We can't upgrade to Rails 4 yet. You said that one of the options is to switch to syck, but we are already using syck. Maybe I was mistaken in thinking that code is being run, by syck also contains this way of serializing big decimals?

Comment: I was referring to ye ole implementaion of `BigDecimal#to_yaml` :-) I'm currently hacking in a Rails console and try to figure out, how to circumvent that said implementaion. As far as I can tell, both engines will convert BigDecimals to floats – despite the conditional `super` call...

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Rails 4.0 or above (but below 4.2), you can work-around it by removing the method `BigDecimal#encode_with`.

You can archive that by using `undef_method`:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'active_support/core_ext/big_decimal'

class BigDecimal
  undef_method :encode_with
end
```

I put this code inside an initializer and now it works.
This "revert" of Rails monkey patch won't be necessary in Rails 4.2, since [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/98ea19925d6db642731741c3b91bd085fac92241) removes the monkey patch.

Answer (score 2):

For rails 3.2, the following works:

```
# config/initializers/backport_yaml_bigdecimal.rb

require "bigdecimal"
require "active_support/core_ext/big_decimal"

class BigDecimal
  remove_method :encode_with
  remove_method :to_yaml
end
```

Without this patch, in a rails 3.2 console:

```
irb> "0.3".to_d.to_yaml
=> "--- 0.3\n...\n"
```

With this patch:

```
irb> "0.3".to_d.to_yaml
=> "--- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.3E0\n...\n"
```

You might like to wrap this in a version test with documentation and deprecation warnings, something like:

```
# BigDecimals should be correctly tagged and encoded in YAML as ruby objects
# instead of being cast to/from floating point representation which may lose
# precision.
#
# This is already upstream in Rails 4.2, so this is a backport for now.
#
# See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031850/getting-big-decimals-back-from-a-yaml-serialized-field-in-the-database-with-ruby
#
# Without this patch:
#
#   irb> "0.3".to_d.to_yaml
#   => "--- 0.3\n...\n"
#
# With this patch:
#
#   irb> "0.3".to_d.to_yaml
#   => "--- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.3E0\n...\n"
#
if Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) < Gem::Version.new("4.2")
  require "bigdecimal"
  require "active_support/core_ext/big_decimal"

  class BigDecimal
    # Rails 4.0.0 removed #to_yaml
    # https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d8ed247c7f11b1ca4756134e145d2ec3bfeb8eaf
    if Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) < Gem::Version.new("4")
      remove_method :to_yaml
    else
      ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "Hey, you can remove this part of the backport!"
    end

    # Rails 4.2.0 removed #encode_with
    # https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/98ea19925d6db642731741c3b91bd085fac92241
    remove_method :encode_with
  end
else
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "Hey, you can remove this backport!"
end
```